# Modified question, but there's no "modified" notice

Tags: discussion, site-information

The question "When do I need to pay interest on my short sell position?" showed up on the front page because "modified 2 hours ago reikred 1".

However, when I click on the link [When do I need to pay interest on my short sell position?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/when-do-i-need-to-pay-interest-on-my-short-sell-position/89660#89660) there's no mention of reikred or any recent modification.

What's up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever you see this, it is almost always due to a deleted answer.

In this case, the user wrote an answer to the question, but then deleted it him/herself immediately.

When you hit 10k rep, you'll be able to see deleted answers on questions.

Comment: I suspected as much, but wasn't sure.  This "we're going to tell you that something's there but aren't going to show you" situation could be construed a bug, but I wouldn't know what policy could fix it...

Comment: @RonJohn It's working as designed, but the design is not because they'd prefer to see it that way - rather, it's a conscious choice to avoid spending the query-resources necessary to do that on the front page.  The front page is an expensive enough query without trying to figure out what you can or cannot see, so instead it just notices modification date and moves on.

Comment: @Joe :) I've had to make those choices before...